# bundle product with configurable options

Tags: configurable-product, bundled-product

I have a item and I wanted to sell them as single, 3 pack, 5 pack and 10 pack.
The product comes in 4 different colors so I want to create a product for each pack and if the customer chooses e.g. the 3 pack i want him to be able to select the color of each single product.

I created 4 simple products (for each color one) and then a configurable product with all them combined.

How can I do this? I tried a bundle product but I can't add a configurable product to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box, however we just implemented this feature for a client using a this module

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/grouped-options.html

It allows for Configurable Products as part of a Group. You can modify it to make it work with bundles

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module [Configurable Bundle 3.0 by Wizkunde](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/configurable-bundle-3-0-by-wizkunde.html)

I have used this in one of my project,this works well for bundle configurable products.